# Variable as attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to use a variable as a value:

```
$("#anything").css({
    "top": value
});
```

But if I try the opposite:

```
toporbottom = "top";
$("anything").css({
    toporbottom: "50px"
});
```

it doesnt work. Is there a elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you don't need an object because you're only setting one property. Use:

```
$(...).css(toporbottom, "50px");
```

If you do want an object, you'll have to make an empty one first, then set the property using the `[...]` notation, and pass `obj`. But this is definitely overkill here:

```
var obj = {};
obj[toporbottom] = "50px"; // `obj["top"]` is the same as `obj.top`
$(...).css(obj);
```

Comment: This works best because I can also use it with .animate()! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can call `css` using the name and value as individual arguments:

```
toporbottom = "top"; 
$("anything").css(toporbottom, "50px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. Use the alternate `.css` syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topOrBottom = "top";

    $("#changeme").css(topOrBottom, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Object literal does not support variable as key. Key should be always constant. However you can use the `[]` to set a property.

```
toporbottom = "top";
var obj = {};
obj[toporbottom] = "50px"; // Line of interest
$("anything").css(obj);
```